# docker exit after executing the command?

Tags: docker, gem5

I need to compile gem5 with the environment inside docker. This is not frequent, and once the compilation is done, I don't need the docker environment anymore.
I have a docker image named gerrie/gem5. I want to perform the following process.

Use this image to create a container, mount the local gem5 source code, compile and generate an executable file(Executables are by default in the build directory.), exit the container and delete it. And I want to be able to see the compilation process so that if the code goes wrong, I can fix it.

But I ran into some problems.

1. `docker run -it  --rm  -v ${HOST_GEM5}:${DOCKER_GEM5}   gerrie/gem5  bash -c  "scons build/X86/gem5.opt"`

When I execute the above command, I will go to the docker terminal. Then the command to compile gem5(`scons build/X86/gem5.opt`) is not executed. I think it might be because of the -it option. When I remove this option, I don't see any output anymore.

I replaced the command with the following sentence.

2. `docker run -it  --rm  -v ${HOST_GEM5}:${DOCKER_GEM5}   gerrie/gem5  bash -c  "echo 'hello'"`
   But I still don't see any output.
3. When I went into the docker container and tried to compile it myself, the build directory was generated. I found that outside docker, I can't delete it.

What should I do? Thanks!

dockerfile

```
FROM matthewfeickert/docker-python3-ubuntu:latest
LABEL maintainer="Yujie  YujieCui@pku.edu.cn"
USER root
# get dependencies

RUN set -x; \
        sudo  apt-get update \
        && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo  apt-get install -y  build-essential git-core m4 zlib1g zlib1g-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libprotoc-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev swig  \
        && sudo -H python  -m pip install scons==3.0.1 \
        && sudo -H python  -m pip install six

RUN apt-get clean

# checkout repo with mercurial
# WORKDIR /usr/local/src
# RUN git clone https://github.com/gem5/gem5.git

# build it
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/gem5

ENTRYPOINT bash
```

I found that when downloading gem5, it may be because gem5 is too big, and it keeps showing `"fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gem5/gem5.git/': GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.`" mistake

So I commented out the
`RUN git clone https://github.com/gem5/gem5.git` command

Comment: how does your dockerfile look like?

Comment: thank you very much! I supplemented the content of the dockerfile file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the entrypoint scons itself.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["scons"]
```

Or absolute path to the bin. I don't know where it will be installed to, you need to check.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/scons"]
```

Then you can run

```sh
docker run -it --rm -v ${HOST_GEM5}:${DOCKER_GEM5} gerrie/gem5 build/X86/gem5.opt
```

If the sole purpose of the image is to invoke `scons`, it would be kind of idiomatic.

Otherwise, remove the entrypoint. Also note, you don't need to wrap it in `bash -c`

If you have removed the entrypoint you can run it like this.

```sh
docker run -it --rm -v ${HOST_GEM5}:${DOCKER_GEM5} gerrie/gem5 scons build/X86/gem5.opt
```

Comment: I just tried it. With the -it option, he just goes into the container. Without -it, nothing will be output.    The Dockerfile for the base image is here. 
 https://github.com/matthewfeickert/Docker-Python3-Ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile Thanks!

Comment: @Yujie, which way did you try? If it was the second one, did you remove the entrypoint? Also did you rebuild your image?

Comment: It was my operation that had a problem. No problem now. Thanks